# How can I get the Steam client to reestablish its connection?

Tags: steam

I've been using the Steam client on my MacBook Pro quite a bit lately, and I've come across a rather annoying issue that I hope one of you can help me with. I often put my computer to sleep with the Steam client still open, and when I open it back up I often see the following:
[image: No connection]
This "lack of connection" (I am very much connected to the internet at this point) presents various grievances such as issues with browsing the store and synching games with the Steam Cloud.

Maybe I simply haven't poked around the menus enough, but I haven't been able to find something that instructs the client to reconnect. I can obviously close and relaunch the client, but that is rather cumbersome and I'm looking for a more elegant solution, if one exists.

Comment: It *should* automatically reconnect shortly after you turn on your computer. It always has for me, at least. I'll have "No Connection" for a minute or two, though.

Comment: Well then, I guess I'm just "lucky" :/

Comment: I feel like one time I had to right click on the Steam icon in the dock and click something to reconnect to the server. I don't have a clear enough recollection to call that an answer, though. Alternately, have you looked under the Account menu to see if the option which is "go offline" when you're connected changes after you wake the computer up?

Comment: I just hit this a couple hours ago and restarting Steam seemed to have livened it up a bit. No idea what made it lose connection, though. My money's on "if your internet is otherwise working, it's probably Steam's fault and all you can do is wait it out".

Comment: See https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/474 for more people with the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this happen often when I put my laptop into sleep mode, and then later start using it again. Sometimes Steam will manage to reconnect itself. When it doesn't, I find I have to close down all of Steam, including its background tasks and then restart the Steam client (which restarts all the background tasks). This always works for me.

Comment: This is exactly my problem, and I suspect that as you've said, there is no solution short of restarting steam when it doesn't reestablish the connection on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Hello fellow MacBook Pro user! I tried going in sleep mode with Steam online on my MBP with Mac OS 10.7.4 and newest Steam and nothing bad, like losing connection after, happened.

I can reconnect by opening **View Friends List** and then **Log In** button.

IMHO that this sleeping issue might be connected with your **[Energy Saver](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2412)** preference panel not **Steam**.

Comment: I thought what you suggest might help, but it does not (for me, at least).

Answer (score 2):

To fix same problem on linux, you need to wrap NetworkManager library (nm-utils.so.2 and nm-glib.so.4) like http://pastebin.com/4WFMbXEc. There is a bug that locks steam while libnm is trying to connect to NetworkManager via dbus when NetworkManager is not installed.